# Delete key-value from object in array, Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$scope.quotes =
    [
        {
            'quote': 'foo',
            'author': 'bar',
            'source': 'foobar',
            'first': 'slideout',
        },
        {
            ...
        },
    ]
```

I'm trying to remove the key-value first: slideout from the array. like this:

```
delete $scope.quotes[0][first];
```

I also tried:

```
delete $scope.quotes[0].first;
```

Comment: Your second attempt will work. If it doesn't then there's some other issue.

Comment: @Kami: That's different. He's trying to remove a key/value pair from a plain object that happens to be in an Array.

Comment: And the first one would work if you had quotes around `first`. E.g., both `delete $scope.quotes[0]['first'];` and `delete $scope.quotes[0].first;` are correct.

Comment: $scope = {};
$scope.quotes =
    [
        {
            'quote': 'foo',
            'author': 'bar',
            'source': 'foobar',
            'first': 'slideout',
        }
];
delete $scope.quotes[0]["first"];
$scope.quotes[0]; // What you have should work.